# How to change the src of iframes or window.opener.location in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iframe

I'd like to change the src attribute of an iframe or the window.opener.location in a for loop. For example like this:

1. Start loop
2. Change src from iframe to link1
3. wait 1 second
4. Next
5. Change src from iframe to link2
6. wait 1 secoond
7. Next
8. [...]
9. End loop

However whenever I try to implement it in a for loop like this:

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = 'http://example.com/index.php?x=init';
for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    console.log(i)
    iframe.src = 'http://example.com/index.php?x='+i;
    sleep(1000) // <- A sleep function that does a while loop for 1000 ms
}
```

it always prints 1,2,3,4,5 in the console before it actually prints the iframe and then changes its src to the last one only.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Is it even possible to implement like that with javascript? Or do I have to do it differently? I have the same problem with for loops and window.opener.location.

Comment: why do you do it in a loop?

Comment: Because I have a variable amount of iterations. It might be 5, it might be 10 sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think what you rather want is something like this.

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = 'http://example.com/index.php?x=init';
var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    console.log(i)
    iframe.src = 'http://example.com/index.php?x='+i;   
    if (i === 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works as intended that way. Is there any explanation on why the for loop didn't work as expected?

Comment: If you show me your sleep()-function, then I can explain it to you.

Comment: It's propably too long to write it here, but basically it is a while loop, that exits as soon as "current time" > "start time + 1000 ms".

Comment: Well, I think for-loops are generally not aware of time restrictions. I've tested a timeout in the for-loop instead of the interval, and the timeouts where all only executed when the for-loop was over. I think the same problem could've been with your while-loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification.